# Is it nessary to destroy a string before constructing it again?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

As an exercise, I'm trying to write a class like a `std::vector` without using a template. The only type it holds is `std::string`.

Below is the `strvec.h` file:

```
class StrVec
{
public:
    //! Big 3
    StrVec():
        element(nullptr), first_free(nullptr), cap(nullptr)
    {}
    StrVec(const StrVec& s);
    StrVec&
    operator =(const StrVec& rhs);
    ~StrVec();

    //! public members
    void push_back(const std::string &s);

    std::size_t size() const        { return first_free - element; }
    std::size_t capacity() const    { return cap - element; }

    std::string* begin() const      { return element; }
    std::string* end() const        { return first_free; }


    void reserve(std::size_t n);
    void resize(std::size_t n);
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

private:

    //! data members
    std::string* element;       //  pointer to the first element
    std::string* first_free;    //  pointer to the first free element
    std::string* cap;           //  pointer to one past the end

    std::allocator<std::string> alloc;

    //! utilities 
    void reallocate();
    void chk_n_alloc()      { if (size() == capacity()) reallocate(); }
    void free();

    void wy_alloc_n_move(std::size_t n);

    std::pair<std::string*, std::string*>
    alloc_n_copy (std::string* b, std::string* e);
};
```

The three `string*`,  `element`, `first_free`, and `cap` can be thought of as:

```
[0][1][2][3][unconstructed elements]
^           ^                       ^
element     first_free              cap
```

When implementing the member `resize(size_t n)`, I have a problem. Say, `v.resize(3)` is called. As a result the pointer `first_free` must be moved forward one place and point to `[3]`. Something like:

```
[0][1][2][3][unconstructed elements]
^        ^                          ^
element  first_free                 cap
```

My question is how should I deal with `[3]`? Leave it there untouched? Or destroy it like:

```
if(n < size())
{
    for(auto p = element + n; p != first_free; /* empty */)
        alloc.destroy(p++);
    first_free = element + n;
}
```

Is the code `alloc.destroy( somePointer)` necessary here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, definitely, you should call `destroy` on elements that are removed from the vector when `resize()` is called with an argument smaller than the current size of the vector. That's what `std::vector` does, too.

Note that `destroy` only calls the destructor on those elements; it does not deallocate any space (which would be wrong).

Since you are dealing with `std::string`, you probably think you could do without destruction if you are sure that you re-initialize the same `std::string` object later with a new value. But firstly, you can't be sure that a new string will be stored in the same place later, and secondly, for the new string a new object would be created (using placement-new, not copy-assignment), leaking the memory of the previous string (whose destructor would never have been called).

Comment: Can you tell me more? I have tried to code it without destroying it. Seems it still works fine. Can you tell me about what are the advantages to do so?

Comment: The key bit of the answer is "leaking the memory".  If you don't destroy it, you'll leave some unusable memory allocated each time you go through this process meaning that applications which use this code will slowly but continually increase the amount of memory they use during any one run.  If you ran a few short tests, this wouldn't cause any notable problems, but if you can much longer ones where this code was called repeatedly, your application could run out of memory and shutdown or could slow down the rest of the system unnecessarily.

Comment: @Alan.W Sorry I had to leave after I wrote the answer. Meanwhile others have provided further clarification. Are there questions left?

Comment: @jogojapan No worries. Learned a lot from your replies and other's. No more questions right now.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do depends on how you've initialised `element`, as you need your code to be consistent.

- if you use `new std::string[n]` to create the array of strings, then they will all be pre-initialised, and when you necessarily use `delete[]` to deallocate them later their destructors will all be run.  For that reason, you must not call the destructors manually in the intervening time unless you are certain you'll placement-`new` a valid object there again.
- if you use something like `static_cast<std::string*>(new char[sizeof(std::string) * n])` to create a buffer of un-initialised memory, then you must take full responsibility for calling the constructor and destructor of every element at appropriate times

With the first option, you wouldn't need to do anything for `resize(3)`, but could call `.clear()` on the string to potentially free up some memory if you wanted.

With the second option, you must trigger the destructor for `[3]` (unless you're keeping some other record of which element eventually need destruction, which seems a clumsy model).

The issues are identical to just having memory for a single string that is "in use" at different times during the program.  Do you spend the time to construct it before first use then assign to it, or do you leave it uninitialised then copy-construct it with placement `new`?  Do you `clear` it when unused or destruct it?  Either model can work with careful implementation.  The first approach tends to be easier to implement correctly, the second model slightly more efficient when the array capacity is much greater than the number of element that end up being used.

Comment: I'd assume he uses `alloc.allocate` to allocate memory for the strings. This corresponds to your second option.