# Is it a good practice to use temporary objects as arguments when overloading functions?

Tags: c++, object-lifetime

Given prototypes:

```
void foo(int i);
void foo(int i, const std::string &s);
```

Implementation:

```
void foo(int i)
{
    foo(i, std::string())   ;
    //!    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^ here?

    //  nothing more.

      }
//!   ^  here?

void foo(int i, const std::string &s)
{
    //do something
}
```

Where does the temporary object created by `std::string()`  go out of scope? Is it a good practise to overload functions this way?

**Update:**

Let me explain a little bit of the situation. As an exercise, I'm trying to write a class like a `std::vector` without using a template. The only type it holds is `std::string`. The class body can be found in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930063/is-it-nessary-to-destroy-a-string-before-constructing-it-again).

When implementing the `resize()` member function, I found that `std::vector` seems are using two functions:

```
  void 
  resize(size_type __new_size);
  void
  resize(size_type __new_size, const value_type& __x);
```

So I'm wondering whether I should use two functions instead of a single one.

Comment: It's really impossible to give a good answer without understanding the intended semantics. If both `foo`'s do the same thing sufficiently that it makes sense to give them the same name, why does the one that takes fewer parameters need to call the one that takes more and then do more stuff? Is that stuff trivial (logging?) or a visible part of the interface such that one `foo` does something externally understood as different from the other?

Comment: With the edit, the question about lifetime doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Hi I've updated the thread. Hope that it makes the situation more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's bad practice, especially if you make `foo(int i)` inline. I can think of a reason when this is preferred: when you create pointers to function, if you declare the second parameter default, you can have only pointer to function that accepts 2 parameters.

The temporary value is alive only as the parameter for the function call.

```
inline void foo(int i)
{
  foo(i, std::string());
}

void foo(int i, const std::string &s)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Why inline it? Make it faster?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not a good practice, at least in this particular case. Use a single function, and a default value for the argument, rather than two functions, one of which only seems to exist to supply a default argument:

```
void foo(int i, const std::string &s = "")
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: It certainly seems to in this case.

Comment: You probably want to say `std::string()` instead of `""`, just in case the implementation happens to allocate memory for an empty literal.

Comment: @meagar Hi! I've updated the thread. Hope that it makes the situation more clearly.

Comment: I agree he doesn't need overloads, but there are still temporary objects present in this solution if a default argument is supplied.

Answer (score 1):

The only "danger" in passing a temporary as `const&` happens if the function creates an object that survive the function call itself that stores in itself a `const&`.

Think to

```
class A
{
   const string& a;
public:
   A(const string& a) :a(a) {}
   void act() { .... /* use a */ }
};

A* foo(const string& s)
{ return new A(s); }

int main()
{
   A* pa = foo(string());
   //here, pa->act() will act on a dangling reference. 
}
```

If your `foo` function just *use* the string, but doesn't retain references for later use, passing a temporary is perfectly safe.

If this happens using a "boot function" or a default temporary value makes no difference for the resulting code.

At that point using one or two function is much more a matter of style and opportunity: how many chances are for the two functions to differentiate during further development?

If the answer is "none: the second function is just THE definition (or a shortcut) for a very frequent case" than default value does perfectly the job.

If the answer is "let's fall back to the other function BY NOW, and later be more specific" then two function are preferrable.

Default values, are however NOT the chance in case the function are templates, and you want type deduction to work:

```
template<class C, class T>
void fn(int i, basic_string<C,T>& s = ????);
```

you cannot use std::string() since it wont work for `C` other than `char`, and cannot use `std::basic_string<C,T>()` since it will not allow to deduce, upon a `fn(5)` call to know what C and T should be.

So you will end-up with

```
void fn(int i) { fn(i,string()); }
```

.